# Zend export database for backup

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework, backup

I want to create a cronjob for making a backup (sql dump) from my database and e-mail it to me. Setting up the cronjob and stuff works great and I'm able to use parts of my zend application :)

Unfortunately I cannot use `exec()` or `system()` on my server so now I'm looking for a way to get the same result. I searched everywhere with all possible descriptions I could think of, but without any results.

So in short:

- I want to backup my databaseup
- Preferably in .sql format (like export in phpmyadmin)
- Using the Zend framework (so I can use my already loaded
  application.ini settings for the database)
- I cannot use `exec()` or `system()`

I'm completely stuck so really anything would help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution by David Walsh looks like what you want:

http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

A php script that retrieves the tables in a database and saves the data in a .sql file.

Comment: Yeah, I know this way and this works fine. But I'm really curious if there is a 'Zend' solution for this.